# Meaning of the $dP(x)$ notation in probability theory.

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I am taking a course on probability which relys a lot on measure theory, and I do not have a lot of background on that area. I am having some troube understanding the notation in some of the examples that appear in my lecture notes:

> Let $U: \Omega \to [a, b]$ a random variable, whose law is $P_U(dx) = \alpha 1_{[a,b]}(x)dx$, where $dx$ is the Lebesgue measure.

or

> Let $X$ be a random variable whose law is an exponential of parameter $\lambda$, that is $P_X(dx) = 1_{\mathbb{R}^+} \lambda e^{-\lambda x} dx$

In both cases $1_A$ is the characteristic function.
I would like to know what the meaning of this notation is, and how it is related to measure theory. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation in your course relates to measure theory as follows: $U:\Omega\rightarrow [a,b]$ is random variable defined on a probability space $\Omega$. The *law* or distribution of this variable is expressed using **[measures](http://galton.uchicago.edu/%7Elalley/Courses/381/measure.pdf)** (Page 3).

For $U$, $P_U(dx)=\alpha \mathscr{1}_{[a,b]}(x)\,dx$ means its distribution is uniform on the interval $[a,b]$, with $dx$ indicating integration with respect to the Lebesgue measure ([Page 4](https://e.math.cornell.edu/people/belk/measuretheory/LebesgueMeasure.pdf)).

For $X$, $P_X(dx)=1_{\mathbb{R}^+}\lambda e^{−\lambda x}dx$ describes an exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$, again using Lebesgue measure for integration. The indicator function  is a function that takes the value 1 on the set $A$ and 0 elsewhere. This notation is central in measure-theoretic probability, which provides a rigorous mathematical foundation for probability theory by using measures.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have a couple more questions:
- Are $P_U(dx)$ and $P_X(dx)$ also measures on $[a,b]$ and $\mathbb{R}$ respectively?
- I have been reading some books on measure theory and I found a theorem that states that given function $F$ that satisfies certain conditions, there is a single measure $\mu_F$ such that $\mu_F((a,b]) = F(b) - F(a)$, and when integrating with respect to that measure we write $\int f dF(x)$ or $\int f F(dx)$. Is that what we are considering here? @Alex Pozo

Comment: @Sergio For the first question:  Yes, $P_U(dx)$ and $P_X(dx)$ can be measures on the interval $[a,b]$ and $\mathbb{R}$, respectively, under certain conditions, i.e, $P_U(dx)$ and $P_X(dx)$ represent the measures induced by the random variables $U$ and $X$, respectively.

For the second question: It is the application of the Lebesgue-Stieltjes Theorem to probability measures.